# Python: How to I save an extracted data from a list, in a tuple(name,num1,num2)?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a file opened, and I'm extracting data from list data. The list data has different names and different numbers for each line in the `for` loop. How do I save each name and its corresponding nums in a tuple? (`name`, `num1`, `num2`).

```
fp = open(file_name, 'r')
   for line in fp:
      line.split('\t')
      line = line.split()
      name = line[0]
      num1 = line[2]
      name2 = line[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the file and create a list of tuples:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
    my_tuples = [(l[0], l[2], l[3]) for l in (line.split() for line in fp)]
```

And if you want names, suggest you make some dicts like:

```
names = "name", "num1", "num2"
my_dicts = [dict(zip(names, line)) for line in my_tuples]
```